# I am using jquery inside the web worker file .But its not working on chrome.messaging system between caller and worker is not working

Tags: jquery

here's my caller file,

*load the worker*

```
var worker = new Worker('./Scripts/worker.js');
```

*register the message event handler*

```
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

if (e.data === "READY") {
```

*print the worker is ready*

```
        $('#messages').append('<li> Worker ready </li>');
```

*enable a button and add a click event handler*

```
        $('#send-message').removeAttr('disabled').click(function() {
```

*send the content of the textbox to the worker*

```
worker.postMessage($('#message').val());

});
```

*place the focus on the textbox*

```
        $('#message').focus();

    } else {
```

*if the message was not ready*
*add the message to the output*

```
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + e.data + '</li>');

        $('#message').val('').focus();

    }
});
```

*here's my worker file,*

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
```

*receive message form page*

```
var message = e.data;
```

*send message to page*

```
    self.postMessage(e.data + 'Processed'); 
});

self.postMessage('READY');
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, please consider adding more details to your question, what exactly is not working? What did you expected? See also how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"I am using jquery inside the web worker file"* No, you aren't -- which is good, because you can't. Web workers don't have DOM access.

Comment: [That code works just fine in Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/hjx2adko/)